# how to create layout folder depending on api version?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

i want to Create  different layout depending api version as follows. Since the default folder layout is already available,when i create new layout as below screenshot it doesnt apppear in android studio folder list under res. but i right click on res and open with explorer those folder does shows. can any one please help me how to create those layout folder.

```
 /res/layout/layout.xml       (Default)
/res/layout-v14/layout.xml   (Api 19)
/res/layout-v17/layout.xml   (API 21)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for not seeing the folders is due to the current viewing option you have selected in Android Studio. (please refer to the image below)

[image]

When `Android` is selected the folders are more compact, meaning it will focus on showing a single resource/folder regardless of qualifiers and I think that's what you experience. Switching to `Project` would solve it however.

This viewing option does have some great benefits by the way, for example I really love how gradle scripts are grouped together and it even shows the Global gradle.properties file (at least on MacOS) which it doesn't in `Project` view.